# Need put variable into object

Tags: javascript

How i can put variable into json
see example

```
$('.thermometer-noconfig').thermometer({

    percent: 10,   
    speed: 'slow'
})
/* thermometers with config */
$('.thermometer-config').thermometer({

    percent: 10, 
    speed: 'slow'
})
```

I need instead of a number "10", I need put variable test 
How I can do that, please help me

Comment: Did you try just replacing `10` with `test` ?

Comment: Also, this isn't json, these are javascript object literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_var = 'whatever'; 
$('.thermometer-noconfig').thermometer({

    percent: 10,   
      speed: 'slow'
    })
    /* thermometers with config */
    $('.thermometer-config').thermometer({

      percent: your_var , 
      speed: 'slow'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myThing = { percent: 10, speed: 'slow' };

mything.percent="test";

var myJsonThing = JSON.stringify(myThing);
```

Now I don't know what the 'thermometer' is / or what it needs - but you can pass either of these :

```
$('.thermometer-config').thermometer(myThing);
```

Or if it needs the JSON format :

```
$('.thermometer-config').thermometer(myJsonThing);
```

---

The output of the `JSON.stringyfy()` on `myThing` is

`{ "percent": "test", "speed": "slow" }`

, but as you are not passing this data to a service over http, I don't know why you are asking for the json format, have to tell us more if so.

Comment: * I see you have removed the reference to json in the question now :P

Comment: Hi 
I need to display some of my calculations as thermometer

Comment: but when I insert my calculations in the function, then it stops working

Comment: here is it 
 $("#start2").click(function(){
G = $("#test").val(); 
H = 10;
D = 0.2;
p_0 = 14.69;
T_0 = 293.15;
Pi= 3.1415926;     
S = 0.25*Pi*D*D;   
V_0 = S*H;
p = p_0 + G/(144*S);
pp0 = p_0/p;
st_pp0 = Math.pow(pp0,5./7.);
V = V_0 * st_pp0;
h = (V_0 - V)/S;
st_pp02 = Math.pow(pp0,-2./7.);
T = 1.8*T_0*st_pp02-459.67;
h2 = h * 156;
T2 = 2*(t-40);
p2 = 2.5(p-10);

$('.thermometer-noconfig').thermometer({

    percent: T2 ,   
      speed: 'slow'
    })
    /* thermometers with config */
    $('.thermometer-config').thermometer({

      percent: h2 , 
      speed: 'slow'
    })
    });

Comment: Hi @user3127698, probally best to ask a new question